While doing Sri Vaishnava Sandhyavandhanam, can everyone do Kesavadi Tarapana?
My limited exposure, I have seen people saying 'tarpanam' has to be done who have lost their parents. So wondering if even I, who have my parents alive, can do that section of the sandhyavandana?

Keshavadi Tarpanam is to be performed by all Sri Vaishnava Brahmins. It is unto Lord Vishnu. Link to this query amongst the Advaita Sampradayam: https://periva.proboards.com/thread/5244/doubt-brahma-yagnam Link to Sri Vaishnava Sandhyavanam: https://www.prapatti.com/slokas/english/sandhyaavandanam.pdf
